# Structure member alignment in GCC version below 4.0.0

Tags: gcc, alignment

When I have just a single array of chars included in a struct like **in6_addr**, what alignment issues should I be aware of when this **in6_addr** is combined with other data types in another struct?

I have an issue on SOLARIS generating bus error using GCC version 3.4.3.

Answer (score 1):

A `char` cannot be misaligned, not even if it's a member of an array. Other data types should still be aligned at appropriate offsets to the start of the structure. Is the structure itself properly aligned?

Comment: It is the leading member followed by an unsigned short in the class. But, when this is aggregated with other classes, somewhere the alignment goes wrong. So, an access to this class member generates bus error. However, when I changed it to an array of bytes in place of **in6_addr**, it has an unaligned address, but doesn't generate a bus fault.

Comment: Show your structure declaration then.  GCC should not be generating a misaligned short following a char array.  It should be adding a padding byte if the array has an odd size.

Comment: Here is the class declaration in essence: